# chrome.downloads.download choose save destination at once

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my `chrome.extension` I want to download files from server using `chrome.downloads.download` API. Every time when I call `chrome.downloads.download()` chrome asks to choose destination to were save file. Is it possible to choose destination at once and download all files to there?

Comment: Looking at the documentation it seems you can do it by specifying `filename`.

Comment: `chrome.downloads.download({url: 'https://***/untitled.jpg',filename: 'untitled-1.jpg'});` every time when to call this function it prompt to choose directory.

Comment: I guess it's because your Chrome is configured to ask the user and the API cannot override that.

Comment: How can I reconfigure it for that?

Comment: Open browser settings, type `download` and toggle that switch.

Comment: Problem with prompt is solved but API didn't react for the `filename` param yet.

Comment: Might be a bug in Chrome.